# How can I match all lines with a certain pattern, except when a certain substring is present?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have multiple lines that have a bit of code that has a format that follow a very simple pattern: `&G3FRM.GetRecord("<TAG>".GetField("<TAG>").Value`. For example, I might have the following:

```
&G3FRM.GetRecord("PAGEREC").GetField("GSHOURS").Value
&G3FRM.GetRecord("RSCH_SETUP").GetField("Y_NIH_MNTHLY_CAP").Value
&G3FRM.GetRecord("PAYMENT").GetField("Y_HRS_TOTAL").Value
```

I need to match anything that has `&G3FRM.GetRecord`, that doesn't have `PAGEREC` as the first string/tag, and is then followed by the rest of the pattern. These statements can appear at the beginning, middle or end of any given line, and there could even be multiple matches in a single line.

This is the Regex pattern that I have tried:

```
&G3FRM\.GetRecord\("(?!PAGEREC)"\)\.GetField\("\w+"\)\.Value
```

As far as I understand, this is matching some literals (`&G3FRM.GetRecord("`) and is then looking for any string that doesn't match `PAGEREC`, using a negative lookahead. It certainly excludes any of the matches that have `PAGEREC`, but it also excludes everything else, so I know that I'm missing something.

So, I have a bunch of lines that I've cherry-picked that could look something like this:

```
Local string &rqst_dept_descr = %This.GetDepartmentDescription(&G3FRM.GetRecord("PAGEREC").GetField("GSREQUESTING_DEPT").Value);
Local string &hoursHTML = GetHTMLText(HTML.G_FORM_ROW_VALUE, "Hours", &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAYMENT").GetField("GSHOURS").Value);
Local string &off_cycle_deposit = &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAGEREC").GetField("GSOFFCYCLE_DIR_DEP").Value;
&G3FRM.GetRecord("POSITION").GetField("GSCOMMISSIONTIPS").Value = "Y";
SQLExec(SQL.Y_HAS_CONTRACT_DATA_IN_RANGE, &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAGEREC").GetField("EMPLID").Value, &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAYMENT").GetField("CONTRACT_NUM").Value, &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAYMENT").GetField("EFFDT").Value, &G3FRM.GetRecord("PAYMENT").GetField("EFFDT").Value, &HasContractData);
```

In this example, it should *exclude* the first line, since it *only* has the pattern I don't want. It should *include* the second line, *exclude* the third, include the fourth, and include the fifth (even though it does have one example of the excluded pattern, it has multiples that I do want).

Comment: Use `&G3FRM\.GetRecord\("(?!PAGEREC")[^"]+"\)\.GetField\("\w+"\)\.Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
&G3FRM\.GetRecord\("(?!PAGEREC\b)\w+"\)\.GetField\("\w+"\)\.Value
```

Note use of `\w+` after negative lookahead to allow it to match a word that must not be `PAGEREC1`. I have added `\b` in your lookahead condition to make sure we don't match partial words.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/locdWd/1)

In your regex `&G3FRM\.GetRecord\("(?!PAGEREC)"\)\.GetField\("\w+"\)\.Value` your negative lookahead condition is correct but regex is not matching anything between 2 double quotes so your regex will only match e.g. `&G3FRM.GetRecord("").GetField("GSHOURS").Value`.